# Apache CXF Handler issue

Tags: spring, soap, cxf, soap-client, cxf-client

I m facing issue with CXF handlers(using CXF version 2.7.6). In my xml file, there are multiple web service clients defined. I have added a simple handler for service 1.

```
<jaxws:client id="service1"
    serviceClass="com.Service1" address="${E1}"
    username="${U1}" password="${P1}">
    <jaxws:features>
        <beans:bean class="org.apache.cxf.feature.LoggingFeature" />
    </jaxws:features>
    <jaxws:handlers>
        <beans:bean class="com.SOAPMessageLoggingHandler" />
    </jaxws:handlers>

</jaxws:client>

<jaxws:client id="service2"
    serviceClass="com.Service2" address="${E2}"
    username="${U2}" password="${P2}">
    <jaxws:features>
        <beans:bean class="org.apache.cxf.feature.LoggingFeature" />
    </jaxws:features>
</jaxws:client>
```

Now the above configuration is resulting in

> org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: The client has been closed.

when the second service (service2) is used and service1 is working fine. But the following configuration is working fine for both services.

```
<jaxws:client id="service2"
    serviceClass="com.Service2" address="${E2}"
    username="${U2}" password="${P2}">
    <jaxws:features>
        <beans:bean class="org.apache.cxf.feature.LoggingFeature" />
    </jaxws:features>
</jaxws:client>

<jaxws:client id="service1"
    serviceClass="com.Service1" address="${E1}"
    username="${U1}" password="${P1}">
    <jaxws:features>
        <beans:bean class="org.apache.cxf.feature.LoggingFeature" />
    </jaxws:features>
    <jaxws:handlers>
        <beans:bean class="com.SOAPMessageLoggingHandler" />
    </jaxws:handlers>
</jaxws:client>
```

Why the order is causing issue? Will handler added to one client impact the other one?